# Default types in a list

Tags: python, list, metaprogramming

In python, how I can construct a list which accepts certain type of parameters at given positions?   For example I like to mandate that first argument should be string and 2nd should be tuple etc.. Possible solution can be creating a class/function  and/or type checking for each elements etc, but are there more structural elements which can do it such as meta-class ?

Comment: That sounds more like a job for your own custom class than a list. Lists are variable-length and typically homogeneous.

Comment: I would think the easiest way to do this would be to create a class with assertions/ifs/try-excepts to your specific types in specific elements. Another owuld be to create a checking function that evaluates your list to see if it matches your criteria

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a good way to do this with lists because they're mutable.  If you don't need a mutable collection, I'd recommend using a tuple (which can be type-annotated with specific types for different positions), or maybe a `NamedTuple` (which has a constructor that takes specific types of arguments).

If you do need a mutable collection, rethink how that's going to interact with your desire to have things strongly typed -- what happens when someone pops an element out of the middle?

Comment: Agreed that `list` is a poor choice of data structure for this. `NamedTuple` is a good suggestion, although it is worth noting that its constructor does not actually verify that the provided attribute values match the expected type.

Comment: If you want useful type enforcement you want to use `mypy`, which does work very nicely with `NamedTuple`.  :)